# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un multiselect y enviar las variables a una api en genexus?

Tags: java, genexus

Tengo un webpanel en el cual selecciono algunos datos en intento enviarlo a un procedimiento que tiene como regla 5 variables que deberían de ser enviadas desde el webpanel, en la parte de patterns y entity services en una transacción que está asociada al webpanel he creado un botón con el nombre de enviar y  al darle f4 he agregado un código en event begin code, este código lo he copiado de la parte de webpanel por que he activado el multidelete en la transaccion y lo estoy utilizando como ejemplo pero yo no quiero eliminar los registros yo solo quiero enviar los datos seleccionados a un procedimiento con el nombre Eliminarrecibo ¿sería algo así como debo hacerlo? este código da error no me funciona

```js
    Event 'enviar'
    Do 'LoadSelectedRows'
    If K2BIsAuthorizedActivityName.Udp(!"PEMTN008", !"PEMTN008", K2BStandardActivityType.Delete, !"",!"")
        If &SelectedRows.Count > 0
            &ConfirmMessage = format('¿Está seguro que quiere eliminar %1 número de recibo procesados?', &SelectedRows.Count)
            &ConfirmationSubId = !"Confirm_DoMultipleDelete"
            TableConditionalConfirm.Visible = True
        Else
            msg("K2BT_NoRowsSelectedError")
        EndIf
    EndIf
    EndEvent
    
    Sub 'LoadSelectedRows'
    &SelectedRows = new()
    For Each line In Grid
        If &Selected = True
            &SelectedRow = new()
            &SelectedRow.PemRenIde = PemRenIde
            &SelectedRow.PemRenAnh = PemRenAnh
            &SelectedRow.PemRenMes = PemRenMes
            &SelectedRow.PemRenNro = PemRenNro
            &SelectedRow.PemRenNdc = PemRenNdc
            &SelectedRow.PemRenLot = PemRenLot
            &SelectedRow.PemRenBen = PemRenBen
            &SelectedRow.PemRenLel = PemRenLel
            &SelectedRow.PemRenBel = PemRenBel
            &SelectedRows.Add(&SelectedRow)
        EndIf
    EndFor
EndSub
Sub 'Confirm_DoMultipleDelete'
    Do 'LoadSelectedRows'
    If K2BIsAuthorizedActivityName.Udp(!"PEMTN008", !"PEMTN008", K2BStandardActivityType.Delete, !"",!"")
        If &SelectedRows.Count > 0
            // Code added in [MultipleDelete.BeginCode] --- START
            &DeletedCount = 0
            &ErrorCount = 0
            For &SelectedRow in &SelectedRows
                &MultipleDelete_BC.Load(&SelectedRow.PemRenIde)
                    //&MultipleDelete_BC.Delete()
                &MultipleDelete_BC = Eliminarrecibo.Udp(PemRenAnh,PemRenMes, PemRenLot.ToString(), PemRenNdc.ToString(), PemRenIde)
                If &MultipleDelete_BC.Success()
                    &DeletedCount += 1
                Else
                    &ErrorCount += 1
                    &ErrorMessage = format('Número de recibo procesado "%1" no pudo ser eliminado por causa de estos errores:', &MultipleDelete_BC.PemRenLot)
                    For &Message in &MultipleDelete_BC.GetMessages()
                        &ErrorMessage += newline() + " - " + &Message.Description
                    EndFor
                    msg(&ErrorMessage)
                EndIf
            EndFor
            If &ErrorCount > 0
                Rollback
                msg('Ningún Número de recibo procesado fue eliminado')
            Else
                Commit
                msg(format('%1 número de recibo procesados eliminados', &DeletedCount))
            EndIf
            Grid.Refresh()
            
            // Code added in [MultipleDelete.BeginCode] --- END
        Else
            msg("K2BT_NoRowsSelectedError")
        EndIf
        
    EndIf
EndSub
```

Bueno este codigo da error al compilar creo que no debe estar en event begin code

```js
error src0062: Expecting 'EndSub' command to close subroutine definition. (Web Panel 'PEMTN008WW' Events, Line: 197, Char: 1, Details)
error src0051: Unexpected expression (Web Panel 'PEMTN008WW' Events, Line: 240, Char: 57, Details)
error: Supported grammar:FOR <variable> IN <array|collection>
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando K2BTools? ¿Qué versión? En caso de que aplique podrías agregar una action y usar la propiedad Row Selection: https://tinyurl.com/3dnb63e6

Comment: si estoy usando la versión 13 K2BTools entiendo si ahora le agrege a mi botón enviar row seleccion multiple haciendo f4 encontre esa opción ¿luego que más debería programar para enviar los parámetros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la propiedad [**Row Selection**](https://wiki.k2btools.com/k2btools/wiki?19961,Row%20selection%20in%20actions) de la action y setear la misma en **Multiple**, esto te va a crear una variable &SelectedRows colección de otra variable &SelectedRow, en estas va a estar la información que tienes en la grilla de los que fueron seleccionados.

Luego en el evento:

```
Event 'Enviar'
   For &SelectedRow in &SelectedRows
       Eliminarrecibo.Call(&SelectedRow.Valor1, &SelectedRow.Valor2, &SelectedRow.Valor3, &SelectedRow.Valor4, &SelectedRow.Valor5)
   EndFor
EndEvent
```

Esto llamaría al proceso por cada uno seleccionado con los valores correspondientes a cada fila.